# Correct way to require modules to prevent eslint erroring

Tags: node.js, eslint

I've recently started using eslint, and I'm finding that all my code is erroring where I have required modules, as it says that the function names aren't assigned.

### mymodule.js

```
module.exports = {
  one: function() {
    console.log(1);
  },
  two: function() {
    console.log(2);
  }
}
```

### index.js

```
require('./mymodule.js');
one(); // eslint says 'one is not defined'
```

Should I be declaring 'one' as a variable beforehand, is that the correct way of doing it? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run your example "index.js" at all (Node 8.15) as the node interpreter itself tells me the same thing eslint is telling you `ReferenceError: one is not defined`. Stuff you export/import from a module doesn't magick itself into the global namespace.

I'd do either of the following:

A) Import the whole of `mymodule`

```js
const mymodule = require('./mymodule');
mymodule.one();
```

B) Import the fun parts of `mymodule` by name

```js
const { one /* , two, three, etc */ } = require('./mymodule');
one();
```

C) Import a single member of `mymodule`

```
const one = require('./mymodule').one;
one();
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is adding a `global` comment at the top of the file:

```
/* global one */

require('./mymodule.js');
one();
```

You can also specify more identifiers as a comma-separated list: `/* global one, two */`.

Alternatively, you can add your undeclared identifiers to the `global` section of your .eslintrc file:

```
{
    ...

    "globals": {
        "one": "readonly"
    },

    ...
}
```

More info: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals